# Numbers not adding correctly

Tags: python

So I am trying to make a list which contains the running total of a list of numbers, however I still want the first number to be displayed without anything being added to it, sort of like this:

Input

```
0.1
0.3
0.2
0.4
0.2
```

Desired Output

```
0.1
0.4
0.6
1.0
1.2
```

Output I am getting

```
0.4
0.6
1.0
1.2
```

Here is the code I am working with:

```
open('widthdepth1.txt','w').writelines([ line for line in open("Test1.txt")    if "WIDTH" in line or "DEPTH" in line])

for line in open("widthdepth1.txt"):
line = line.strip("")
parts = line.split(":")
category = parts[0]
value = parts[1]

with open("widthdepth1.txt") as f:
width =  [line.split(":")[1] for line in f if "WIDTH" in line]
widthtotal = float(width[0])
h = open("WidthValue1.txt", "w")
for line in width[1:19]:
widthtotal += float(line)
h.write(str("%0.4f" %widthtotal)+"\n")
print ("%0.4f" %widthtotal)
```

I am new to python so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
widthtotal = float(width[0])
h = open("WidthValue1.txt", "w")
for line in width[1:19]:
    widthtotal += float(line)
```

`widthtotal` already contains 0.1 before the loop begins, and `0.3` gets added to it before you print anything. So it's not too surprising that `0.1` doesn't get printed. Try initializing `widthtotal` to zero and iterating over the full `width` collection instead.

```
widthtotal = 0
h = open("WidthValue1.txt", "w")
for line in width:
    widthtotal += float(line)
```